# Ble Device not connect to peripheral randomly android

Tags: android, connection, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm using ble service for connect peripheral but have strange problem with connection some times the following method not connect the device and some times it works perfectly the ratio is 10:1

```
private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
    if (enable) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
                connectToPeripheral();
            }
        }, 15000);
        mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    } else {
        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }
}

Method connectToPeripheral is for connection and data receiving,I stuck with problem since long time don't have any idea why this happening if i kill the app than connect still have same problem.is it problem of Advertising delay?
```

Comment: http://www.argenox.com/blog/android-5-0-lollipop-brings-ble-improvements/